# Allow VRRP on firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, icmp

Deploying an HA redundant solution we use Keepalived with VRRP traffic and a virtual IP. So far I enabled VRRP traffic with the following command (working):

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=dmz  --add-rich-rule='rule protocol value="vrrp" accept' –permanent
```

However the client is asking which port is used by  to enable the traffic. As far I understand, VRRP is using ICMP messages to notify Keepalived alive.

Is it a satisfactory condition if I ask for ICMP traffic to be allowed to keep VRRP/Keepalived working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, VRRP is not part of ICMP, nor vice versa – it's a standalone protocol with its own packet format.

However, although it runs on top of IP, VRRP does not use a transport protocol and does not have "ports". Rather, it runs *alongside* TCP/UDP/ICMP and has the IP protocol number 112.

Comment: Can you explain what this 112 ip protocol number states? We are also trying to setup HA with keepalived but clients are only allowing us to open certain ports and I have noticed that keepalived is not changing states from master to backup and vice versa am assuming there are some restrictions. What should I do or what ports shall I open between 2 servers so that keepalived can work between them.

Comment: "Open" to *where*, though? Are you talking about restrictions on the hosts themselves or about a network-level firewall? It doesn't matter if there are outbound firewall restrictions on the network – they have no effect on same-subnet communications which are direct. VRRP traffic doesn't go out to the Internet and back.

Comment: open to each other (Bi Directional communication between both servers) they are requiring exact ports, only those will be opened for communication rest everything restricted.

Comment: In that case, tell them that they need to allow _protocol_ 112 and that it is neither TCP-based nor UDP-based and therefore has no TCP/UDP port.

Comment: Alright Thank you